# Should I avoid the usage of the http-equiv="content-type" meta tag in html?

Tags: html, content-type, meta-tags

I see some people recommending putting  in the head of all of their html. Our server is sending a content-type http header, so I dont believe this is needed. Am I correct? Are their any reasons to keeping the meta tag?

A reason I wish to remove it is because Google mentions that IE8 may suffer in performance if content-type is defined in a meta http-equiv tag rather than in http headers. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering?hl=it#SpecifyCharsetEarly

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to put it there if your server is setting the correct headers. The headers are the preferred, standard way of setting the content type.

BTW don't forget to accurately put your charset in the content type too!